# Angular Material date picker changes insane date when changed it manually and pressed tab

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have used [Angular material date picker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) control here. It has a weird issue on my component. i.e. it is fine when I selected it using calendar control. But if I changed the date manually and then press a tab button it goes for a completely insane date. Any clue on how to avoid this? I don't have any date initialization or something like that here. I have tested with reactive forms also but the same behavior. This insane date changes for different values. i.e. not the same insane date

*.html*

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker">
          <mat-icon matDatepickerToggleIcon>keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
        </mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Behavior:

[image]

Comment: You can make the field readonly user will not able to enter date manually.

Comment: @Tushar No. I need that feature for good UX.

Answer (score 0):

I think for your requirement you should create custom date adapter.
Check this example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hv6jny-ynqfb2

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's all about **useValue** How you are showing the date format in date picker. it should match with  **dateInput**

```
parse: {
    dateInput: 'DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss',
  },
providers: [
    {
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useClass: MomentDateAdapter,
      deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]
    },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: FORMATS },
  ]

export const FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'DD-MMM-YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};
```